# How do I get the JWT in a Blazor Server App with Microsoft Identity Platform (AAD) to make external API-Management call and authorize with the jwt

Tags: jwt, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side, azure-api-management, microsoft-identity-platform

The situation I have:

- Blazor Server App , .Net6.0.9 with Microsoft Identity Platform.
- Blazor Server App is registered in the App Registration on Tenant-1
- Client-API-1 is also resigered in the App Registration on Tenant-1
- Login actions are done against/with the ClientId of the Client-API-1 registration and work fine.

[image: Infrastructure]

In the API-Management I've added on the Inbound processing Polecies Validate-jwt like this:
([source of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#configure-a-jwt-validation-policy-to-pre-authorize-requests))

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid!!!">
        <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/11a14169-89cc-44e8-95d7-xxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
       <required-claims>
            <claim name="aud">
                <value>{client-id-of-Client-API-1-on-App-Registration}</value>
            </claim>
        </required-claims>
    </validate-jwt>
```

In Service looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace BlazorSAAppJwt.Data
{
public class ApimService : IApimService
{
    private AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider { get; set; }
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

    public ApimService(AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
    {
        _authenticationStateProvider = AuthenticationStateProvider;
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    }

    //public async Task<string?> GetResponseAsync(string path, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    public async Task<string?> GetResponseAsync(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            if (authState?.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
            {
                using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://apimanagement.azure-api.net/");
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("email", authState.User.Identity.Name);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "{My APIM suvbscriptionkey}"); // APIM
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Trace", "true");

                // This gets the UserToken to get data from Microsoft Graph for the scopes: User.Read & Mail.Read
                var token = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "User.Read", "Mail.Read" });

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token);
                var dataRequest = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me");
                string? userDisplayName = "";
                if (dataRequest.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var userData = System.Text.Json.JsonDocument.Parse(await dataRequest.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
                    userDisplayName = userData.RootElement.GetProperty("displayName").GetString();
                }

                //Remove the previous Authorization-header for the Microsoft Graph call
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Remove("Authorization");

                //Add the Application token to the Authorization for APIM
//NOTE!!! Here is where the JWT token should be used!!!!
                string jwt = "How do I get the jwt here to add and send to the APIM";
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {jwt}");

                //HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{path.ToLower()}", cancellationToken);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{path.ToLower()}");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string clientApiResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    return clientApiResult;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException($"(Graph) User Display Name: {userDisplayName}" +
                        $"{Environment.NewLine}Response from APIM call: {response}");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // "The user is NOT authenticated.";
                throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();
            }

            return default;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var iets = ex.Message;
            throw;
        }
        
    }
}
}
```

I receive the UserDisplayName from the Graph API-call.

My program.cs

```
using BlazorSAAppJwt.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var initialScopes = builder.Configuration["DownstreamApi:Scopes"]?.Split(' ') ?? builder.Configuration["MicrosoftGraph:Scopes"]?.Split(' ');
var azureSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd");
var microsoftGraphSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph");

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
            //.AddMicrosoftGraph(microsoftGraphSection) // Nuget Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddTokenAcquisition();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ApimService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

What do I miss, and how do I setup my Blasor Server App to use the JWT token?

EDIT:
The API-calls on the APIM is not going to change and will call the Client-Api that is not exposed to the internet.

Comment: after using AAD for authentication and authorization, you don't have to use APIM, APIM is expensive and is more suitable for apis which can't be changed a lot... You can expose api in azure ad and use it to protect your api..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who knows that the call:

```
var token = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "User.Read", "Mail.Read" });
```

Retruns the JWT... It does and what it is you need to use in the request header

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token);
```

And make the call

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{path.ToLower()}", cancellationToken);
```